# Thousands of TaskCanceledException exceptions

Tags: asp.net, azure, exception, redis, stackexchange.redis

Over a period of ~24 hours we received thousands of errors on one specific server for all page loads.  The errors take the form:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 4/20/2019 1:43:47 PM 
Event time (UTC): 4/20/2019 1:43:47 PM 
Event sequence: 554231 
Event occurrence: 12592 
Event detail code: 0 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6888 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TaskCanceledException 
    Exception message: A task was canceled.
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Wait(Task task) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 543
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisSubscriber.StackExchange.Redis.ISubscriber.Subscribe(RedisChannel channel, Action`2 handler, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisSubscriber.cs:line 471
   at C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Redis.PubSub.PubSubController.SubscribeToCacheKey(RedisChannel cacheKey, Action`2 onMessageReceived) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Redis\PubSub\PubSubController.cs:line 45
   at C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Manager.Manager.Callbacks.OnGotten[T](String cacheKey, CacheType fromType, T objectGot) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Manager\Callbacks.cs:line 99
   at C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Manager.Manager.Get[T](String key, Func`1 getFromExternFunction, Boolean skipLocalCaches) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Manager\Manager.cs:line 131
   at C3.PageControls.Forums.TopicRender.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\PageControls\Forums\TopicRender.ascx.cs:line 42
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

     Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 448 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Wait(Task task) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 543
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisSubscriber.StackExchange.Redis.ISubscriber.Subscribe(RedisChannel channel, Action`2 handler, CommandFlags flags) in C:\projects\stackexchange-redis\src\StackExchange.Redis\RedisSubscriber.cs:line 471
   at C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Redis.PubSub.PubSubController.SubscribeToCacheKey(RedisChannel cacheKey, Action`2 onMessageReceived) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Redis\PubSub\PubSubController.cs:line 45
   at C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Manager.Manager.Callbacks.OnGotten[T](String cacheKey, CacheType fromType, T objectGot) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Manager\Callbacks.cs:line 99
   at C3.Code.Controls.Application.Caching.Manager.Manager.Get[T](String key, Func`1 getFromExternFunction, Boolean skipLocalCaches) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\Code\Controls\Application\Caching\Manager\Manager.cs:line 131
   at C3.PageControls.Forums.TopicRender.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Construct.net\Source\C3Alpha2\PageControls\Forums\TopicRender.ascx.cs:line 42
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

The exceptions appeared to of cleared up on their own afterwards.  Am lost on what could possible be causing these errors.  Does anyone know the cause?

All our nuget packages are up to date, as is our webservers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you subscribed or consuming Azure Cache for Redis at the Basic, Standard, or Premium pricing tier ([Service Tier Comparison](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/))? I believe you have experienced a cache service interruption. The Premium tier offers Redis clustering, which will mitigate any service interruptions. The Standard tier offers replication for disaster recovery but any service interruptions will need to be mitigated through a `retry` mechanism in your application. Basic tier offers only a single node and has no replication or clustering capabilities.

Also, please ensure you are implementing the `HomeController` class through a similar method, per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-web-app-howto) tutorial.

```
public ActionResult RedisCache()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "A simple example with Azure Cache for Redis on ASP.NET.";

    var lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        string cacheConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheConnection"].ToString();
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
    });

    // Connection refers to a property that returns a ConnectionMultiplexer
    // as shown in the previous example.
    IDatabase cache = lazyConnection.Value.GetDatabase();

    // Perform cache operations using the cache object...

    // Simple PING command
    ViewBag.command1 = "PING";
    ViewBag.command1Result = cache.Execute(ViewBag.command1).ToString();

    // Simple get and put of integral data types into the cache
    ViewBag.command2 = "GET Message";
    ViewBag.command2Result = cache.StringGet("Message").ToString();

    ViewBag.command3 = "SET Message \"Hello! The cache is working from ASP.NET!\"";
    ViewBag.command3Result = cache.StringSet("Message", "Hello! The cache is working from ASP.NET!").ToString();

    // Demonstrate "SET Message" executed as expected...
    ViewBag.command4 = "GET Message";
    ViewBag.command4Result = cache.StringGet("Message").ToString();

    // Get the client list, useful to see if connection list is growing...
    ViewBag.command5 = "CLIENT LIST";
    ViewBag.command5Result = cache.Execute("CLIENT", "LIST").ToString().Replace(" id=", "\rid=");

    lazyConnection.Value.Dispose();

    return View();
}
```

And are calling the correct FQDN for the cache, as this is important if you are subscribed to the Premium tier but only pointed at one instance in the cluster.

If you [investigate this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-monitor) and find you are seeing timeout or multiple disconnect issues, the following [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-faq#why-am-i-seeing-timeouts) has some guidance on this specific issue.